# Create native library in android studio

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, ndk-build

I have created android studio project with c++ support and installed native development kit and other required tools. How to import another prebuilt native library to include in c++ code. I want to do something like this
[image: I want to do something like this]

I have edited cmakelist.txt as given below and now it show shared library under cpp folder.
[image]

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
set(distribution_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../distribution)
add_library(lib_gmath STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_gmath PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
${distribution_DIR}/gmath/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libgmath.a)
add_library(lib_gperf SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_gperf PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
${distribution_DIR}/gperf/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libgperf.so)
add_library(lib_ocr SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_ocr PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
${distribution_DIR}/ocr/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libLPROCR.so)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")
add_library(hello-libs SHARED
        hello-libs.cpp)
target_include_directories(hello-libs PRIVATE
                       ${distribution_DIR}/gmath/include
                       ${distribution_DIR}/gperf/include)
target_link_libraries(hello-libs
                  android
                  lib_gmath
                  lib_gperf
                  lib_ocr
                  log)
```

But i am not able to include classes from that prebuilt library in my c++ code.

Comment: It's documented here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts

Comment: @RichardCritten I have already read that multiple times but i am not getting it. It says give module a name and then edit module android.mk but i don't see any such thing in project structure.

Comment: Are you looking for the exposed API of libLPROCR.so?

Comment: @AlexCohn Yes, source code probably.

Comment: Why do you think this library may be hi useful for you?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that I should mention here.

1. I suggest to switch to `gradle+clang` for building your code. `Android.mk` is somehow getting old and it is better to use newer build systems if you are starting new project.
2. Make sure that your prebuilt library can be used in android. If it is not, you need to build it first. For example I built openssl myself because I could not find a suitable prebuilt library.

In case your are using `gradle+cmake`, here is a simple `CMakeLists.txt` file for your prebuilt libraries:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( core-api
             SHARED
             src/main/cpp/mysource.c )

# prebuilt libraries

add_library( crypto-lib
             STATIC
             IMPORTED )

set_target_properties( crypto-lib
                       PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../prebuilt/crypto/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libcrypto.a )


include_directories( src/main/cpp/
                     ../prebuilt/crypto/common/include/
                     ../prebuilt/crypto/${ANDROID_ABI}/include/ )

# other libraries

find_library( log-lib
              log )

target_link_libraries( core-api
                       crypto-lib
                       ${log-lib} )
```

And this is a `gradle` file that uses this `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.sdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static"
                cFlags "-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS", "-fno-integrated-as"
            }
        }

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    cFlags "-Wall","-DDEBUG"
                }
            }

            debuggable true
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: i am using gradle+cmake and edited cmakelist.txt similar to yours. I can see prebuilt library under cpp folder marked as shared library. Prebuilt library is working fine in other projects. But how to use that lib code in my c++ code ? i can't include files. i dont have include header file  but only .so file.

Comment: You really need include headers. if you have exported `C++` class, you cannot find classes without header files. you may find `C` exports if you know name exactly, but for `C++` you almost cannot(it will be super hard). if your prebuilt library is shared, you need to use `add_library(crypto-lib SHARED IMPORTED)` and other setting should be similar I guess.

Comment: Okay thanks. i don't have include headers but only .so file. I will look on web if can find source code of that pre-built library.